# Is Angel Wealty fake?

Tags: trading, fraud

I traded on the Angel Wealty platform. I don't know if it's fake or not. And he wanted me to pay taxes. He said that I had done the authentication incorrectly and also asked for money. Is this platform fake or real?

---

See edit history for original question in Turkish